# How to return certain number value with java script from html

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I need custom javascript code for Google tag manger to create variable for transaction value. To do this I need a code that return number 30.99 from HTML:

```
<span class="price-data">zł30.99</span>
```

I wrote some code but it doesn’t work:

```
function() {
var orderValue = document.getElementsByClassName(‘price-data')[0].value;
return orderValue.match((\d*\.\d*)|(\d*));
}
```

Could you help me with that

Comment: It looks like you're using two different types of speech marks surrounding price-data, might want to correct that and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: a span does not have a `.value`, use `outerText` or `innerHTML` or something else...and your regex looks suspect, use `.replace('zł','')` or another regex for example `.match(/([\d\.]+)|([\d])/)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

See the following snippet. Check the console value.

```js
var orderValues = document.getElementsByClassName('price-data');

var orderValue = orderValues[0].innerHTML;  
var match = orderValue.match(/([\d\.]+)/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

```html
<span class="price-data">zł30.99</span>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you found this to be the right answer, the community would appreciate you accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

"I need custom javascript code for Google tag manger " - no, you don't. You need a DOM type variable with the selector method set to "CSS selector" and the selector set to your class name. This will return the text content of the first element that matches the selector.

[image]

Since GTM already carries a selector engine around you really gain nothing by writing custom Javascript.